# Execution failed for task :app:compileReleaseKotlin. in flutter project

Tags: flutter, android-studio

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:
  Execution failed for task ':app:compileReleaseKotlin'.

> A failure occurred while executing org.jetbrains.kotlin.compilerRunner.GradleCompilerRunnerWithWorkers$GradleKotlinCompilerWorkAction
> Compilation error. See log for more details

- Try:

> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.

- Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 1m 35s
Running Gradle task 'assembleRelease'...                           96.7s
Gradle task assembleRelease failed with exit code 1

i tried by changing java home and invalidating cache and restart the android studio. but still the same   error happen !

Comment: The actual cause will be outputted _above_ that log - that log is used as a catch-all for all of the Kotlin compilation errors that were outputted by the compiler.